# Jekyll generator not loaded

Tags: jekyll, generator

I currently experienced an issue with Jekyll generators. Just implemented one regarding AMP. So I placed it inside the `_plugins` folder, and named it `amp_generate.rb`.

Tried to add some `puts 'foo'` but nothing on my terminal...

Giving a look at `jekyll serve -V`, it seems the generator never appears...

Any idea? Here is the source code : https://github.com/tiste/www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running in `safe: true` mode (like on github pages) because `gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins` instruct jekyll to run in github pages context.

Simply change to `gem 'github-pages'`.

You can even simplify your Gemfile to be :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby RUBY_VERSION
gem 'github-pages'
```

Comment: Thanks!  Simple fix once you know what was causing the generator not to run.